# How can I change the X axis of my plotly graph to represent the dates stored as row headers in my pandas dataframe? Python For Finance Cookbook 2020

Tags: python, plotly, finance, yahoo-finance, plotly-python

I am going through the book 'Python For Finance Cookbook' written in 2020 published by Packt. In ch 1, plotly is used to graph stock price, return and log returns. However plotly updated their documentation right after the publication of the book so I am having a hard time replicating the plot. Here is the link to the repo https://github.com/erykml/Python-for-Finance-Cookbook/tree/master/Chapter%2001 . I want to plot 3 line graphs on top of one another using the same x axis, which would be the date. I got this, but i cant change the x axis to reflect the year, it is stuck on counting number of days from 1990 to 2020. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd 
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
init_notebook_mode()

df = yf.download('MSFT', auto_adjust = False, progress=False)
df = df.loc[:, ['Adj Close']]
df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': 'adj_close'}, inplace=True)

df['simple_rtn'] = df.adj_close.pct_change()
df['log_rtn'] = np.log(df.adj_close / df.adj_close.shift(1))

df.dropna(how = 'any', inplace = True)


px.line(data_frame=df, title='MSFT time series')

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, 
                    shared_xaxes=True, 
                    vertical_spacing=0.02)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y = df['adj_close']),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y = df['simple_rtn']),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y = df['log_rtn']),
              row=3, col=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, lol very simple fix. I just set `x=df.index`